# How to updated all row's field of one table from data of another table with one time query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have added a new field in data_entry table and want to insert on that the value of employee_write_task table's `emp_id` based on `employee_write_task.task_id = data_entry.id and employee_write_task.empType_id = 1.` 'here 1 is type of task for data_entry'

I have tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO data_entry (emp_id) 
SELECT emp_id FROM employee_write_task 
WHERE employee_write_task.task_id = data_entry.id AND employee_write_task.empType_id = 1
```

but it doesn't seems to work. What am I missing?

I have attached tables and it's attributes below for references.

[image: MySQL Queries.]

Comment: try `upadte data_entry de join employee_write_task ewt on ewt.task_id = de.id set de.emp_id = ewt.emp_id where ewt.empType_id = 1`

Comment: it returns `Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'upadte data_entry de set de.emp_id = ewt.emp_id join employee_write_task ewt on ' at line 1
`

Comment: @Anil please check it 

update data_entry d,employee_write_task e
set d.emp_id=e.emp_id
where d.id=e.task_id AND e.empType_id = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using update statement instead of insert. Try like follows.

```
UPDATE data_entry set emp_id =  
    (SELECT emp_id FROM employee_write_task 
    WHERE employee_write_task.task_id = data_entry.id AND employee_write_task.empType_id = 1)
```

This query may fail if the below select retrieve more than 1 value.

```
SELECT emp_id FROM employee_write_task 
    WHERE employee_write_task.task_id = data_entry.id 
    AND employee_write_task.empType_id = 1
```

In such case, you should add few more conditions to uniquely term the record.

Regards.

Comment: Ok, but what about subqueries, I mean what if there is multiple data in subqueries..

Comment: thats what i have already mentioned in my answer. If there are more than 1 row returned from your sub query, you have to add few more conditions in your where clause to restrict it to return 1 row per emp_id to get updated.

Comment: Thanks man. It seems to be work correctly. But something shit is happening in my database tables, data are not updated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE  data_entry
LEFT JOIN employee_write_task
ON      data_entry.id = employee_write_task.task_id
SET     data_entry.emp_id = employee_write_task.emp_id
WHERE   employee_write_task.empType_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update data_entry d,employee_write_task e
set d.emp_id=e.emp_id
where d.id=e.task_id AND e.empType_id = 1;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10354358)

Comment: @GAMITG what kind of detail you need in above query?

Comment: Add explanation of that query.